# Angular Material md-select does not show selected Item (bind issue)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-material

When I select an item, it does not bind. What am I doing wrong?

HTML Code:

```
<md-input-container data-ng-init="LoadListOfThings()">
  <label>Things</label>
  <md-select ng-model="object.Item" required name="item" >
      <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in itemList track by item.Id">
        {{ item.Name }}
      </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

JS:

```
$scope.LoadListOfThings= function () {
    $http.get('api/ControllerBla/GetListOfThings').then(function (response) {
        $scope.itemList = response.data;
    }, function (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    });
};
```

Comment: What is `object.Item` ?

Comment: Also, in the future, please use `angularjs` for Angular 1 questions, as `angular` is reserved for Angular version 2+

Comment: @borislemke, the "object.Item" is an empty object "$scope.object = [];" initially.
Thanks for the advise of angularjs vs angular.

Comment: did you try by swapping `ng-repeat` and `ng-value`? So you repeat first before you use the value?

Comment: anyway, you initiate an empty Object with `{}` not `[]`. That would be an empty array

Comment: @borislemke, I corrected the initiation of the objects. Now is like that:
$scope.itemList = [];
$scope.object = {};
$scope.object.Item = {};

I changed the order of the html code too, but it's not working yet. =(

Comment: @borislemke, I realised what I was doing wrong.

My ng-model was a property of an complex object "$scope.Empresa.NomeFantasia", when I changed that for a simple variable "$scope.NomeFantasia", it works.

I don't know why it doesn't work with a complex object, I have initialized everything correct.

Comment: did you do `$scope.Empressa = { NomeFantasia: {} }`? That should work

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show the real code in a plunker. You stated that you use a complex object(`$scope.Empressa.NomeFantasia`) but in this question you simplified the example, it may be easier to help if you show the actual code

Comment: @borislemke, I'm new on this stackoverflow system. And was affraid to put some codes here.

But, I did what you said and it still not work.  $scope.Empresa = { NomeFantasia: {} }; I think maybe it's because of the moment that it initializes. I will just use a simple object. Thanks for your time and solutions, you are a very good programmer!

Comment: glad you found a solution! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `track by item.Id` in `ng-repeat` use `ng-model-options`
Example :

```
<md-input-container data-ng-init="LoadListOfThings()">
 <label>Things</label>
 <md-select ng-model="object.Item" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" required name="item" >
  <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    {{ item.Name }}
  </md-option>
 </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: I already tryed that. It did'nt work. And what's funny, when I put "{trackBy: '$value.id'}", it initiates selected the both items, but them I can't change it.

But when I put "{trackBy: '$value.Id'}" with the upper case "Id", the issue continues the same.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I realised what I was doing wrong!

My ng-model was a property of an complex object "$scope.Empresa.NomeFantasia", when I changed that for a simple variable "$scope.NomeFantasia", it works.

It was like that:

`$scope.Empresa = {};
 $scope.Empresa.NomeFantasia = {};`

But it only works with that:

```
$scope.NomeFantasia = {};
```

I don't know why it doesn't work with a complex object. I think I have initialized everything correct.

Answer (score 0):

ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.region.id'}" will solve problem

ex:-